# Device Twin IoT Hub - get tags from JSON in python

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I have a question. I would like to get "tags" from JSON from my device twin in IoT Hub.
I'm trying to do this with IoTHubRegistryManager:

```
iothub_registry_manager = IoTHubRegistryManager(CONNECTION_STRING)
iothub_registry_manager.get_device(name)
```

but I will receive like that only partially JSON with:

```
additional_properties
device_id
generation_id
etag
connection_state
```

and so on but I can not see the "tags" key which is the most important for me. Do you have maybe some suggestions on how I can get this from python?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to call `get_twin` instead of `get_device`, e.g.

```py
twin = iothub_registry_manager.get_twin(name)
```

You will notice that the [Twin](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/9216065ad79d5ecea4caae2d3aaeaa432ef18c53/azure-iot-hub/azure/iot/hub/protocol/models/twin_py3.py#L11) model in the source code and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-iot-hub/azure.iot.hub.iothub_registry_manager.iothubregistrymanager?view=azure-python#get-twin-device-id-) returns a `Twin` [object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-iot-hub/azure.iot.hub.protocol.models.twin_py3.twin?view=azure-python) which has a `tags` property, unlike the `Device` [object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-iot-hub/azure.iot.hub.protocol.models.device(class)?view=azure-python) which does not.